# design a complex card in the flutter

Tags: flutter

What is the best way to design the following card?

[image]

I do not know use `card` or design it with (`container/row/column/....`)

How can I achieve that?

Comment: hi, are you a novice in flutter?

Comment: yes, It's your right.

Comment: for first timer you need to understand layout,it help to breakdown you design to skeleton model of you design before doing the design ,refer following site,it help to understand how things works `https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e`,`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJEnTRBxaSg`@DarushHamidi

Comment: I think, you should try this by yourself, because this is a easy task and you learn lots of widgets information from this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the information is too rough to give the advice. Though Card Widget is easy to use but lots of properties are not able to change (like border, shadow of the card). I suggest
you can study the Card widget first and define a custom card widget if it is not fit your layout.

For custom widget, I think `container/row/column` can do most of the layout. Only the avatar may need to use `BoxDecoration`(also in Container) or `ClipOval`. Setting can use `Stack` widget (need to overlay).